# i want to show discount price when a product has discount price

Tags: python, django

i have this Order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    disc_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(datetime.datetime.today, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default="Unpaid", unique=True)
    order_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=CHOICES, null=True, blank=True, default="In Review")
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(
        PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    total = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.all()
        if order.disc_price:
            self.total = self.quantity * self.disc_price
        else:
            self.total = self.quantity * self.price
            return super().save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here I have disc_price i want like this. Like if a product has disc_price the save function will be like this

return self.disc_price * self.quantity

I tried above but it is not working can someone help !

Comment: please remove return from the else block and try it. Here only the else conditions work.

Answer (score 0):

The save method includes the `self` property which is the instance that is being saved. The super method should be called in both discount and regular cases.

*** There was also an error on the date field - the datetime methods does not set the current date, but the apps's last start date.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    disc_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default="Unpaid", unique=True)
    order_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=CHOICES, null=True, blank=True, default="In Review")
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(
        PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.disc_price:
           self.total = self.quantity * self.disc_price
        else:
            self.total = self.quantity * self.price
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: i applied this method but its not working !

Comment: I missed that the super call syntax was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

try this it might work,

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.disc_price:
       self.total = self.quantity * self.disc_price
    else:
        self.total = self.quantity * self.price
    return super().save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```